# Time is defaulting to "2000-01-01 21:14:00 UTC" in rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and working on an application.
On my form, the default time that I am looking to achieve, (EST time) is not correct and although there is a drop down box for the user to select  the correct date and time, it reverts back to "2000-01-01 21:14:00 UTC".

Any suggestions on what can be done to avoid this?

Currently my jobs_controller.rb looks like this:

```
  def new
@job = Job.new(:date => Time.now, :date_of_loss => Time.now, :sign_date => Time.now, :time_called_in => Time.now)
end
```

Comment: Your question is missing some information, e.g. what do you mean by "default time", when do you observe a "revert back", how does you current code look like..?

Comment: @PeterSorowka I need it to default to EST

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've probably created those columns as `:time` columns in your migrations. If you want to save time of day and date, then you need a datetime column.

Confusingly, even though the ruby `Time` is used to represent a point in time (and from that point of view is very similar to the `DateTime` class (but very different in terms of implementation)) in sql a `TIME` column is different and means a disembodied time of day, with no date attached (for example the concept of 4pm).

Ruby doesn't have a built in class for time of day, so rails chose to represent those with a Time instance. Since the date portion is ignored it is set to an arbitrary date, which happens to be January 1, 2000

Comment: would I have to change a type in my migration? how do i fix this. Can I simply add something in my controller? like Time.zone.now.utc?

Comment: You would indeed need to change the type of the column (to :datetime). Easiest way is to create a migration to do this change

Comment: Thank you will get on that asap I appreciate you getting back to me

Comment: Sorry to be a bother I have generated a migration and currently my code is as follows: class ChangeDateFormatInJobsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

  end
end      Can I put change_column? what is the best approach?

Comment: That should do it - plenty of questions on migrations here.